# randomly choosing a function from a list then apply conditions to the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

In the code below, `a`, `b`, and `c` are pre-defined functions that are a part of much bigger code. The code is always returning the `elif` part even if the choice is `enemy_def`. I have tried printing each one but nothing happens.

```
a = enemy_hit
b = enemy_def
c = enemy_sphit
d = [a,b,c]
enemyresponse = random.choice(d)()
#print(enemyresponse)
if enemyresponse == b :
   thing.health = thing.health - 0.25
   #print(enemyresponse)
elif enemyresponse != b :
     #print(enemyresponse)
     thing.health = thing.health - 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enemy_reponse` will never be equal to `b`*, because `enemy_reponse` is the return value of the function, not the function itself. Note how you call the function immediately after randomly choosing it:

```
random.choice(d)()
#               ^Called it
```

Save the function that was chosen in a variable called `chosen_function` (or something similar), then check against that.

You probably meant something like this (untested):

```
a = enemy_hit
b = enemy_def
c = enemy_sphit
d = [a,b,c]

# Randomly get function from list
chosen_function = random.choice(d)

# Call it to get the return value
func_return = chosen_function()
print(func_return)

if chosen_function == b:
   thing.health = thing.health - 0.25

else:
   thing.health = thing.health - 1
```

*Unless `b` returns itself, which seems unlikely.

Comment: is their a way around this can i randomly chose without calling , i mean can i call it wihin the if \ else  statements or can i do this if I did not assign the functions to variables

Comment: @HasanFares Yes, just don't put the `()` after the call to `choice`. It's those parenthesis that cause the function to be called.

Comment: i tried but all it returns is :                                                                                function start.<locals>.enemy_sphit at 0x005E84F8>

Comment: @HasanFares That's the chosen function. You need to call it somewhere. enemy_reponse is a function, not a value.

Comment: @HasanFares See the updated code. I've fixed it up so it's readable and less redundant.

Comment: how is enemyresponse a function i'm not getting it , i mean haven't i assigned the randomchoice function to it , you mean i sholud  put e = enemyresponse ,would this save the result

Comment: @HasanFares Again, look at the updated code in my answer. And a, b, and c are all functions, so if you randomly pick one of them, you'll get a function back.

Comment: i noticed the elif but i saved it since i'll be adding more moves in the future

Comment: @HasanFares OK, then disregard that suggestion regarding `else`.

Comment: @HasanFares No, it's ok, it just seemed for a sec that you were ignoring my suggestions. I've had it where I spent half an hour helping someone, and they never posted back or thanked me, which is kind of a slap in the face. I was worried that may have been the case here. Glad I could help you though! And on this site, the way to thank someone (besides saying it) is to upvote their answer.

Comment: those functions are a part of a bigger function that calls them and returns the final combined result at  its end

Comment: @HasanFares OK, I see. From just this snippet here, it wasn't clear exactly how the code worked. You can ignore those points at the bottom if they aren't relevant.